# What happens if a ResendRequest gets lost or the initiator is not able to answer it?

Tags: fix-protocol

Consider the following sequence diagram which depicts the communication between a FIX initiator and the acceptor. Please note I am refering to **FIX.4.4** here.

[image]

As you can see the message with sequence number 2 gets lost in transit. The initiator sends another message (with seq. number 3), the acceptor detects that gap and issues a resend request, asking again for message with seq. number 2 and everything that might have followed (`7=2|16=0`).

A couple of questions that I couldn't get answered by digging through the spec:

- What happens if the "Resend Request" gets lost in transit?
- What happens if the initiator is not able to resend the requested messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens if the "Resend Request" gets lost in transit?

The gap will be detected on the subsequent message just as you lined out.

However, the `ResendRequest` will not actually be resent because the only session-level message that must be resent is the `Reject` message.
Instead, either a `SequenceReset` with `123/GapFillFlag=Y` [(description)](https://fiximate.fixtrading.org/legacy/en/FIX.5.0SP2/tag123.html) will be sent or the message will be skipped with a `SequenceReset` message with `36/NewSeqNo` set to a higher sequence number, effectively skipping the message that will not be resent.

This is stated in the FIX spec in chapter "message recovery" [(link)](https://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/fixt1.1/section_session_protocol.html#MessageRecovery)

> What happens if the initiator is not able to resend the requested
> messages?

As stated above it should either send a `GapFill` instead, or skip to a higher sequence number.

Comment: Thx for replying. Is this also valid for FIX.4.4? It seems this is related to FIXT 1.1. Sorry, I have mentioned that in my original question - fixed now.

Comment: This is definitely applicable to ALL FIX versions.

Comment: Okay great. So only the receiving side (acceptor) can send `SequenceReset` message?

Comment: Do you refer to your example? Because no, every side can send `SequenceReset` messages

Comment: Okay, but when refering to my example where the `ResendRequest` got lost in transit: The acceptor would send a `SequenceReset` (reset mode) in response to the next received out-of-sync message. Correct?

Comment: Umm, no. When any side *detects* a gap (i.e. receives an out-of-sync message) it sends a `ResendRequest` to request the missing messages. When any side wants to *fill a gap* in response to a `ResendRequest` of the other side, it will either resend the missing messages, or send a `SequenceReset` in either `Reset` or `GapFill` mode. See the paragraph starting with "Upon receipt of a Resend Request<2>" in the link I posted (chapter "message recovery").